# Creación de figuras en html y css

Tags: html, css

Vuelvo a formular la pregunta de mejor manera.
Necesito hacer una infografia como la siguiente utilizando html y css puro.

[image: Imagen de una infografia]

Por el momento llevo el siguiente código
HTML:

```
        <div class="container justify-content-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="in-circle"></div>
          <div class="info-card">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem possimus distinctio ex.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.in-circle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 30px #AD0306;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.info-card {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 20%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 115px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 8px 0px rgba(225, 229, 238, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 8px 0px rgba(225, 229, 238, 1);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 8px 0px rgba(225, 229, 238, 1);
}

.info-card h3 {
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
}

.info-card p {
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
}
```

Pero tengo problemas para distribuir los elementos a como se muestra en la imagen.
Si alguien me pudiera ayudar a hacerlo de una mejor manera, ya que entiendo que mi código tiene muchas deficiencias y hay maneras mejores de hacerlo, lo agradecería mucho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede hacer de esta forma:

- Usando position: `absolute` y `relative` para colocar los elementos en un lugar en específico
- Usaremos `border-radius` para establecer la forma tanto del círculo como también del listón que *cuelga* del último círculo
- Usamos la propiedad `box-shadow` para establecer el efecto de sombreado
- Envolvemos los 3 círculos dentro de un contenedor general al cual le aplicamos un `display` con el valor de `flex` para que los 3 elementos se alineen sobre el *main axis*
- El acomodo de elementos o `divs` lo hacemos de esta forma:

  - Un contenedor padre
  - El contenedor padre tiene al círculo hijo y al mismo tiempo tiene el div que servirá como listón de información
  - Al final pero dentro del mismo div padre colocamos al div nieto que será el último círculo
- Usaremos:

  - nth-child(2) para identificar que valor vamos a modificar y poder identificar al segundo círculo padre
  - Usaremos tanto `first-child` como `last-child` para encontrar tanto al primer como al último círculo y de esta forma modificar sus colores
- En la seudoclase `root` declaro las variables de elementos tales como:

  - El color de fondo del círculo hijo que es el único que se repite en los 3 de la infografía
  - El color de fondo del listón que también es el mismo en los 3 círculo
  - El color de sombra de cada uno de los 3 listones

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        :root {
          --circulo-hijo: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
          --liston-info: #FFFFFF;
          --liston-sombra: 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
        }
        .infografia {
          display: flex;
        }
        .circulo-padre {
          border-radius: 50%;
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          position: relative;
        }
        .circulo-hijo {
          background-color: var(--circulo-hijo);
          border-radius: 50%;
          width: 170px;
          height: 170px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 15px;
          left: 15px;
        }
        .circulo-nieto {
          background-color: #F5B014;
          border-radius: 50%;
          height: 100px;
          width: 100px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 34px;
          left: 34px;
        }
        .liston-informacion {
          position: absolute;
          height: 180px;
          width: 110px;
          background-color: var(--liston-info);
          top: 30px;
          left: 30px;
          border-radius: 55px 55px 60px 60px;
          box-shadow: var(--liston-sombra);
        }
        /*modificación 1*/
        .circulo-padre:last-child .circulo-nieto {
          background-color: #83C74C;
        }
        .circulo-padre:last-child {
          background-color: #83C74C;
        }
        /*modificación 2*/
        .circulo-padre:nth-child(2) {
          background-color: #F85B26;
        }
        .circulo-padre:nth-child(2) .circulo-nieto{
          background-color: #F85B26;
        }
        /*modificación 3*/
        .circulo-padre:first-child .circulo-nieto {
          background-color: #ECAD29;
        }
        .circulo-padre:first-child {
          background-color: #ECAD29;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section class="infografia">
      <div class="circulo-padre">
      <div class="circulo-hijo">
          <div class="liston-informacion"></div>
        <div class="circulo-nieto">
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="circulo-padre">
      <div class="circulo-hijo">
          <div class="liston-informacion"></div>
        <div class="circulo-nieto">
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="circulo-padre">
      <div class="circulo-hijo">
          <div class="liston-informacion"></div>
        <div class="circulo-nieto">
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

El resultado luciría así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta y el cambio del titulo, la verdad tengo que aceptar que se me da muy mal explicar y redactar, por cierto me funciono excelente  y te agradezco grandemente por la ayuda